# how to get rid of the a page in the url on angular 2 after leave

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Ok, let me explain to make it easy to understand

so basically I have to routes

- localhost:5555/find
- localhost:5555/productName-productId

when I head to **/find** route and click on any product it goes to the **productName-productId** but it shows on the url `localhost:5555/find/xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx`
it works well but I need to rid of that `/find` in the url and just be `localhost:5555/productName-Id`

**item.component.html**

I've been trying in here to get rid of it but it shows the `find`

```
    <a [routerLink]="[getTitleUrl(data.details.model, data.details.make ), whip.id ]">
    .....
    </a>
```

**item.component.ts**

```
  getTitleUrl(make, model ): string{
    //convert spaces into -
    var make = make.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    var model = model.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    //concat
    let title = model +'-'+ make;

      return '../'+ title ; // adding '../' solved the problem
  }
```

**home-routing.module.html**

```
    ...
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
          { path: 'find', component: FindItemComponent},  
          { path: ':title-:id', component: ItemDetailComponent },      
          { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
          { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
          { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }  
        ])
      ]
    })
    ...
```

**find.component.html**

```
<app-item *ngFor="let item of items| slice:0:15| truncate; let i=index"></app-item>
```

Comment: Could you show this method's content? `getTitleUrl(data.details.model, data.details.make)`

Comment: I just did... also find a quick solution..

Comment: was about to suggest that, lol. You could simply add that as the first argument to the `routerlink` in your template (if you don't wanna modify the method). `<a [routerLink]="['/', getTitleUrl(data.details.model, data.details.make ), whip.id ]">`

Comment: cool!!..I did it with null before but didn't work..